# How to determine transaction ID of PO in Quickbooks Desktop Enterprise?

Tags: import, quickbooks

I'm attempting to use [Zed Axis 11.2](http://www.zed-systems.com/products/axis.aspx) to import some item receipts into QB. I'd like to have the item receipts linked to the PO. Axis allows such a link, but I don't know what the transaction ID of the PO is. How do you get the transaction ID of a PO in Quickbooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there needing the info:

The only way I found to get the transaction ID is to export the transaction (to XML or other format). The exported file has, in most cases, the transaction ID.